# Using two printers with different paper formats alternating

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

I use one ordinary ink jet printer with A4 paper size and one thermo label printer with 4x6 inch paper format. I configured those standard paper format in each printer device's settings. Nevertheless, this setting seem to be ignored because every time I'm in the print dialogue, the defined paper format is the one I had chosen in the previous print job, no matter which printer it was. Because I use both printers literally alternating, I have to change the paper format for the particular printer for every print job which is very annoying. Instead I would expect the configured paper format of the particular printer to be used by default, so that I don't have to change it each and every time.

My system is Ubuntu Linux 20.04. I print PDFs (with evince) and PNG images (with eog) or with Firefox. For the printing I don't want to use command line tools.

Comment: Silly question perhaps but have you set the different values for the different printers in Settings > Printers

Comment: Yes, I did configure the default paper in each printer but those settings seem to be ignored.